17th/18th century British red coat officer hurt during battle and loses sight
I have been really wanted to watch this movie literally FOR YEARS but I can't remember the name of it, so hopefully you can tell me the name of the movie!
The only stuff I remember of it is that it's about this soldier (from the 17th/18th century), an officer I think, that gets sent to the battlefield somewhere. The red-coats are not so lucky and the coolest thing I remember was that they arranged their formation in the famous "square" formation (that was the first time ever I saw that happening). After that I think his pistol explodes in his face or something like that and therefore he loses sight (this happens towards the end of the battle). Then, he somehow goes back to the UK, I suppose England and he visits the girl that he was in love with, but he does not have eyes, just the scars from the pistol explosion.
I can't remember if this was part of this movie but I think that after the battle where he loses his sight he gets captured along with his mate and is enslaved.
This movie looked pretty old, it was probably shot during the 80's, maybe early 90's, but it was in color.

The Four Feathers contains some of these elements, but in 2 different versions. In the 1978 version, the British officer is blinded by a rifle's flare and in the 2002 one, it's a heatstroke; however, his scars there are more like the ones you described. Both versions contain infantry square scenes and most of the details are similar (the officers are captured and later return to England and reunite with their loves), but the plot takes place in the 19th century.
The entire 1978 version is available here (where the officer is blinded around 47:15), and here's a clip with the blinded officer in the 2002 version:



